# Zend Lucene Search - Update index - Is it possible?

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene, zend-search-lucene

I am implementing Zend Lucene search in my website. Now I am doing my index updation by deleting the old index by its id and re creating it. But I would like to know whether it is possible to update the index instead of deleting and recreating it. If possible please provide me steps.

Hope to get your queries soon.

Cheers..!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from Zend framework documentation:

> Once an index segment file is created, it can't be updated. New
>   documents are added to new segments. Deleted documents are only marked
>   as deleted in an optional .del file.
>
> Document updating is performed as separate delete and add operations,
>   even though it's done using an update() API call Zend_Search_Lucene
>   API. This simplifies adding new documents, and allows updating
>   concurrently with search operations.